# Service Contracts not visible in Customer Portal

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I'm running Vtiger 7 on PHP 7.

Service contracts can be enabled from the admin configuration [image]

But Service Contracts are not visible in the Customer Portal [image]

Is this because of some bug or is this feature not fully added to Customer Portal yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi panchtatva please execute this Queries in your database

```
INSERT INTO `sandeep_forexcrmdb`.`vtiger_customerportal_prefs` (`tabid`, `prefkey`, `prefvalue`) VALUES ('35', 'showrelatedinfo', '1');
INSERT INTO `sandeep_forexcrmdb`.`vtiger_customerportal_tabs` (`tabid`, `visible`, `sequence`) VALUES ('35', '1', '12');
```

and check Service Contract Module display or not